# How to write from textbox to file? C#

Tags: c#, list, textbox

I want to get data from textbox and write it to file. I have this code, but it's not working.

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string info = textbox2.Text;
        List<string> data= new List<string>();
        data.Add(info);
        String line = File.WriteAllLines(filename, data);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _How_ isn't it working, then?

Comment: Where is filename coming from here? Also have you ensured that your click event is being triggered? 

btn.Click += (s,e) => Button_Click_2(s,e);

Comment: Why you create a list? Its useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** you are trying to store the `return` value of the function `File.WriteAllLines()` into `String`  variable `line` but `File.WriteAllLines()` does not return anything it's return type is `void`

**2.** you can use `File.WriteAllText()` function to write your string entered in `TextBox`.

Try This :

```
    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {                
        File.WriteAllText(filename, textbox2.Text);
    }
```